# stack/unstack operations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading about stack, unstack in python for data analysis using pandas.

```
>>> data
number    one  two  three
state                    
Ohio        0    1      2
Colorado    3    4      5
```

// unstack: this pivots from the rows into the columns.

```
>>> data.unstack()
number  state   
one     Ohio        0
        Colorado    3
two     Ohio        1
        Colorado    4
three   Ohio        2
        Colorado    5
dtype: int32
```

////////////////// Stack makes columns in to rows

```
> >>> result = data.stack()
> >>> result state     number Ohio      one       0
>           two       1
>           three     2 Colorado  one       3
>           two       4
>           three     5 dtype: int32.
```

My question on above is if unstack is to pivot rows in to columns, why columns one, twot three are moved as rows in above example

Another question is that does stack/unstack always moves to innert most level.

Comment: there is a [level parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) associated with unstack - though I can't test it right now, it seems like it would help you

Comment: What happened was that unstack did indeed pivot the row index (state) to level 1 in columns.   But since ther is just one row of data, Pandas converts this to a multiindex series.     That is way it is listed vertically.  Yes, stack and unstack added to the inner most level and since level indexes start with zero outside going in, it is adding a new level with an increment on the current level index.

Comment: @ scott. can you briefly explain what does you mean by since there is o ne row. I am not getting here. Actually there are two rows here