# How to convert dataframe column to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like

```
Name   keywords  Count
User1  aws        14
User1  ec2        4
User1  python     1
User2  aws        12
User2  ec2        5
User2  python     6
User3  aws        17
User3  ec2        7
User3  python     8
```

and so on...

I want to convert values in both Keywords and Count column to rows like except the header 'keywords' and 'Count'

example

```
Name    aws   ec2  python
User1   14    4     1
User2   12    5     6
User3   17    7     8
```

Comment: You can also try to set a MultiIndex and stack/unstack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365893/stack-unstack-operations-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced your dataframe with:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
"""
Name,keywords,Count
User1,aws,14
User1,ec2,4
User1,python,1
User2,aws,12
User2,ec2,5
User2,python,6
User3,aws,17
User3,ec2,7
User3,python,8
"""
), sep=",")
```

Then using [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to produce your desired dataframe:

```py
>>> df.pivot(index="Name", columns="keywords", values="Count")
... keywords  aws  ec2  python
... Name                      
... User1      14    4       1
... User2      12    5       6
... User3      17    7       8
```

Note that this creates the name as an index. If you would like to have name as as column instead you can reset the index as such:

```
>>> df.reset_index()
... keywords   Name  aws  ec2  python
... 0         User1   14    4       1
... 1         User2   12    5       6
... 2         User3   17    7       8
```